# String Lines in Variable in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to monitor services and start them when the startmode is Auto.

```
$WMI = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | 
Where-Object { $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Software Protection' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Google Update Service (gupdate)' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Google Update-service (gupdate)' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Pml Driver HPZ12' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Shell Hardware Detection' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Group Policy Client' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Multimedia Class Scheduler' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Skype Updater' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Remote Registry' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'TPM Base Services' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Windows Update' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Windows Modules Installer' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Smart Card'} | Select DisplayName,State
```

In my case this gives me two results when executing:

```
$displayname = $WMI | select Displayname
```

Result:

```
DisplayName                                                                                                                            
-----------                                                                                                                            
SQL Server Agent (JOURNYX)                                                                                                             
Performance Logs and Alerts
```

I can't get it to work using `foreach`

This is because in the end when i am using `Start-Service $displayname` it tries to start `@{DisplayName=SQL Server Agent (JOURNYX)}`

This is my script now:

```
$WMI = Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | 
Where-Object { $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Windows Image Acquisition (WIA)' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Software Protection' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Google Update Service (gupdate)' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Google Update-service (gupdate)' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Pml Driver HPZ12' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Shell Hardware Detection' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Group Policy Client' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Multimedia Class Scheduler' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Skype Updater' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Remote Registry' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'TPM Base Services' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Windows Update' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Windows Modules Installer' -and $_.DisplayName -notlike 'Smart Card'} | Select DisplayName,State 


$displayname = $WMI | select Displayname

foreach ($servicename in $displayname) {

try {

start-service $Servicename.DisplayName -ErrorAction stop

Write-host "Service" $servicename.displayname "started, after being failed"

exit 1001

}

catch {

Write-Host "Tried to start" $servicename.displayname "Service, but failed"

exit 1001

}

}

write-host  "Services reporting OK" 
Exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an object $WMI, with the values state and displayname in it.

When you do the `$displayname = $WMI | select Displayname`, you still have an object, which is named `$displayname` now, and have a value called `displayname` in it. So you need to reference that value:

`Start-Service $displayname.displayname`.

In some cases it is better to use `Start-Service $($displayname.displayname)`, so PS can evaluate the value, before it is used as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks Martin. That is what i usually do, but does not work:

$displayname.displayname is empty.

And yes, i did run the WMI command

Start-Service $($displayname.displayname)
Start-Service : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.

Comment: Ah okay. $Displayname is still an Array of objects, sou you should see `$displayname[0].displayname` and so on. Try to use `$($servicename.displayname)`  in your  `start-Service` statement.

Comment: Thanks, $displayname[0].displayname did work.

Unfortunately, i only get one of the two to return a message.

Tried to start SQL Server Agent (JOURNYX) Service, but failed

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass 'name' attribute to Start-Service.

```
gwmi win32_service | ? {$_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running'} | Select -ExpandProperty Name | Start-Service
```

Please add your filters in Where-Object(?).

Comment: Hi, Thank you!

This helped. I did use your part of the script:

Now it is: 

`$WMI = gwmi win32_service | ? {$_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running'} | Select -ExpandProperty Name

if ($wmi.Count -ge 1) {

Foreach ($servicename in $WMI) {

try {

Start-Service $servicename -ErrorAction stop

write-host "Service" $servicename "started, after being failed"


 }

catch {

write-host "Tried to start" $servicename "but failed"

}

}

}

else {

write-host  "Services reporting OK" 
Exit 0

}`

Comment: Too bad it does give me an other view of the service. Displayname is much clearer.

Comment: If you need DisplayName, then first create an object of Get-Service before you do Start-Service.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it to:

`| select displayname` instead of `-expandproperty name` in the first line

After the foreach, before `try {` i added `$servicename = $servicename.displayname`

Now it works fine